# Li bullets/dots too high: how to vertically center

Tags: html, css

My `li` bullets/dots sit too high. How can I make them vertically centered with the first line of text?

```css
ol,li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol {
    counter-reset: foo;
    display: table;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: table-row;
}

li::before {
    content: "•";
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .3em;

  color: $mht-blue; 
  font-size: 225%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
  <li>
   How can I make the dot vertically lower? Ie, centered on the first line of text? sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Why not flex instead of table?

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao do you mean a literal `table` with css `flex`? This is all part of a CMS website so users will be generating `ul`'s and I need the default list look (above) to cascade through. I dont think tables will work.

Comment: No, I meant applying `display:flex` instead of `display: table` as the data is not tabular

Comment: Also, I just noticed the html has `ul` but the css has `ol`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` on the `li`, then either alter the `line-height` so it's short and `font-size: 225%` on the bullet will align with the font size beside it, or just remove that `font-size` entirely if you don't mind the button being smaller.

```css
ol,li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol {
    counter-reset: foo;
    display: table;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    counter-increment: foo;
    display: flex;
}

li::before {
    content: "•";
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: .3em;
  color: $mht-blue; 
  font-size: 225%;
  line-height: .6;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
  <li>
   How can I make the dot vertically lower? Ie, centered on the first line of text? sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
 </ul>
```